# Header tag clarification -- <h1>,<h2> etc

Tags: html

HTML Heading Tags – what is the purpose of it?

I can always use the style to define the text size I want then why I need HTML Header tag?

Even though it says header tag it can be used anywhere in the html body to display the content. It need not be used only in header of the page but can be used anywhere. Header is confusing tag name for me. Is the same for others?
Thank you for the clarification.
Smith

Comment: "header"?  "headings tags"?  You mean `<head></head>`?

Comment: please define what a heading tag is

Comment: Do you mean `<h1>,<h2>,` etc.?

Comment: `<h1>This is a heading</h1>` put it at the top of your page

Comment: http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/f/blfaqheadings.htm

Answer (score 4):

Because header elements (`<h1>`...`<h6>`) are NOT about the text size. They're used to mark true, logical *headers* - and not just some chunks of text that should be displayed with bigger letters or something.

These *logical* headers of text, in turn, can be used in many ways - to index the document, for example, to calculate its relevance for some search terms etc.

Comment: ^ This!! Think of the way a wikipedia page works: h1 is the title of the page, h2s are the subsections (the ones used to populate the in-page navigation) that divide up content into logical chunks

Answer (score 1):

Heading tags contain semantic information; they're not just about font size.

http://ablognotlimited.com/articles/the-beauty-of-semantic-markup-part-3-headings 
http://blogs.creative-jar.com/post/Semantic-HTML-the-h1-tag-and-SEO.aspx 
http://www.pearsonified.com/2007/04/definitive-guide-to-semantic-markup.php